Responsive Design in Custom Painter and Stack in Flutter
I have been trying to create something like this in Flutter,

I tried using CustomPaint for it because of the bottom right sharp thing.
and I use stack to set texts on it.
The problem is that this is not responsive; on some devices, texts are not where they should be.
how can I fix this?
The widget
Stack(
    alignment: widget.alignment,
    children: [
      CustomPaint(
        size: Size(context.width, ((context.width) * 0.58).toDouble()),
        painter: widget.painterWidget ,
      ),
    Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            right: 8.0,
            left: 8.0,
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: context.width,
            child: Column(
....

The CustomPaint
class NotificationCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
// Layer 1

Paint paint_fill_0 = Paint()
  ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
  ..strokeWidth = size.width * 0.00
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
  ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;

Path path_0 = Path();
path_0.moveTo(size.width * 0.9608333, size.height * 0.0714286);
path_0.quadraticBezierTo(
    size.width * 0.9980167, size.height * 0.0702571, size.width * 1.0025000, size.height * 0.1414286);
path_0.cubicTo(size.width * 1.0020833, size.height * 0.2489286, size.width * 1.0017917,
    size.height * 0.5629000, size.width * 1.0013750, size.height * 0.6704000);
path_0.quadraticBezierTo(
    size.width * 1.0005583, size.height * 0.7403286, size.width * 0.9597083, size.height * 0.7454000);
path_0.quadraticBezierTo(
    size.width * 0.2732333, size.height * 0.7409286, size.width * 0.0432333, size.height * 0.7409286);
path_0.quadraticBezierTo(
    size.width * 0.0030750, size.height * 0.7389714, size.width * -0.0011833, size.height * 0.6743571);
path_0.quadraticBezierTo(
    size.width * 0.0008833, size.height * 0.2457071, size.width * 0.0009000, size.height * 0.1366571);
path_0.quadraticBezierTo(
    size.width * -0.0007333, size.height * 0.0698000, size.width * 0.0441667, size.height * 0.0700000);
path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0516167, size.height * 0.0029429);
path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.0800000, size.height * 0.0677000);

canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_fill_0);
}

@override
 bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
   return true;
 }
}


You can use ShapeBorder for this.  Play on gist or dartPad
/// Create a pointy shape like toolTip
///
/// ```dart
///  Container(
///    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
///      shape: PointyShape(
///        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
///        pointOffsetX: pointX,
///        pointyHeight: 24,
///        radiusValue: 16,
///        isTop : true,
///      ),
///      color: Colors.white,
///    ),
///```
///
class PointyShape extends OutlinedBorder {
  const PointyShape({
    this.pointOffsetX = .85,
    this.radiusValue = 16,
    this.pointyHeight = 24,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(12),
    this.isTop = true,
  }) : assert(pointOffsetX >= 0 && pointOffsetX <= 1, "offset should be within 0,1");

  final double pointOffsetX;
  final double radiusValue;
  final double pointyHeight;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool isTop;

  @override
  OutlinedBorder copyWith({BorderSide? side}) => this;

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => padding.copyWith(
        bottom: padding.bottom + (isTop ? 0 : pointyHeight),
        top: padding.top + (isTop ? pointyHeight : 0),
      );

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return getOuterPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final rRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
      Rect.fromLTRB(
        rect.left,
        rect.top + (isTop ? pointyHeight : 0),
        rect.right,
        rect.bottom - (isTop ? 0 : pointyHeight),
      ),
      Radius.circular(radiusValue),
    );

    final pointyStartX = rect.right - (rect.width * (1 - pointOffsetX)) - pointyHeight / 2;

    final toolTip = isTop
        ? (Path()
          ..moveTo(pointyStartX + pointyHeight / 2, rect.top)
          ..lineTo(pointyStartX, rect.top + pointyHeight)
          ..lineTo(pointyStartX + (pointyHeight), rect.top + pointyHeight)
          ..lineTo(pointyStartX + pointyHeight / 2, rect.top))
        : Path()
      ..moveTo(
        pointyStartX,
        rect.bottom - pointyHeight,
      )
      ..lineTo(pointyStartX + (pointyHeight / 2), rect.bottom)
      ..lineTo(pointyStartX + (pointyHeight), rect.bottom - pointyHeight)
      ..lineTo(pointyStartX, rect.bottom - pointyHeight);

    return Path.combine(PathOperation.union, Path()..addRRect(rRect), toolTip);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}


Great answer, can you update it so a pointy shape can also be added to the top of the rectangle?

added and  I will recommend  to play with it in order to learn

You don't need to use Stack widget, create your entire shape with CustomPainter and put your data in that widget, in this way  your app looks more responsive,
 Paint paint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.white// Set the color of the square
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill; // Fill the shape

// Create a path for the rounded square
double radius = 20.0; // Radius for the corners
var arrow_side = size.width/10;
var height = size.height - 15;
var arrow_start_point = 15;

Path path = Path()
  ..moveTo(radius, 0) // Start at the top-left corner
  ..lineTo(size.width - radius, 0) // Move to the top-right corner
  ..arcToPoint(Offset(size.width, radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius)) // Top-right corner
  ..lineTo(size.width, height - radius) // Move to the bottom-right corner
  ..arcToPoint(Offset(size.width - radius, height), radius: Radius.circular(radius)) // Bottom-right corner

 ..lineTo(size.width - radius-arrow_start_point, height)

  ..lineTo(size.width - radius-arrow_start_point - arrow_side/2, size.height)
  ..lineTo(size.width - radius-arrow_start_point - arrow_side, height)
  ..lineTo(radius, height) // Move to the bottom-left corner
  ..arcToPoint(Offset(0, height - radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius)) // Bottom-left corner
  ..lineTo(0, radius) // Move to the top-left corner
  ..arcToPoint(Offset(radius, 0), radius: Radius.circular(radius)); // Top-left corner
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

Usage with custompaint widget:
 Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 180,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: NotificationCustomPainter() ,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("ثبت خرید و دریافت جایزه")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )



Hi Hesam, Thanks for your response. I tried your approach. it was working fine on mobile. I tested it in Flutter Web, and some phones still have overflow issues.
I added this as width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 150

If the overflow caused of Text widget put it inside widgets like Flexible, FittedBox or any responsive technique for text, your shape now is a normal widget you've several options to make it responsive

It's not a direct answer to your question, but you can try this package; https://pub.dev/packages/info_popup
I put widgets such as Tabbar and ListView into it and ran it, it is very flexible and adaptable.

Thanks for your response but this won't work for my case which is a Coach mark.
